# Rewrite rule is not working

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want a custom rewrite rule for my plugin. But for some reason it is not working. I tried flushing url, registered query var. But still it wont work and it gives output like this:

```
http://domain.com/page_name/?gallery_id=6
```

URL without prettifying:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?page_id=5&gallery_id=6
```

I want to rewrite above url to:

```
http://domain.com/page_name/gallery/id
```

I have added custom query var `gallery` and `gallery_id`. Here is my rewrite rule:

```
"pagename/gallery/([^/]+)/?" 
    => "index.php?page_id=".$base_page_id."&gallery_id=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: can you show us the full code in context including where you add the query var? also, you should be using [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to add a rule.

Comment: This issue is fixed. actually this rewrite rule is working when I browse to this URL, but this link are not updated to pretty url when I enable permalink.